# How to sum with Null Values in group by statement using agg function in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
A   B       C
a   100     200
a   NA      100
a   200     NA
a   100     100
b   200     200
b   100     200
b   200     100
b   200     100
```

I use the aggregate function on column B and column C as:

```
ag=data.groupby(['A']).agg({'B':'sum','C':'sum'}).reset_index()

Output:

A  B     C
a NULL  NULL
b 700   600

Expected Output:

A  B     C
a 400  400
b 700   600
```

`How can I modify my aggregate function so that NULL values are ignored?`

Comment: For me working well...

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ? Are columns `B,C` filled by numbers?

Comment: B: float64 and C: int64

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: It worked fine for me.

Comment: The pandas version is 1.0.3

Comment: Weird, pandas by default remove NaNs in `sum`

Comment: @jezrael has valid point Take a look at [`pandas/core/base.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py#L159) `np.sum`, `np.nansum`, `"sum"` all are mapped to the same cython function in `_cython_table`, `NaN` is handled by default. Don't know what's the problem and we can't reproduce your output.

Comment: @Ch3steR - yop, no idea what is problem

Comment: maybe your `NULL` is string?

Comment: @Manakin Can't be OP mentioned `dtypes` as `B: float64 and C: int64`

Comment: Can an Integer column even contain NaNs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already though about this but is not possible in your problem, but you can replace the NA values by 0 in the dataframe before this operation. If you don´t want to change the original dataframe you can transform it in a copy.

```
ag=data.replace(np.nan,0).groupby(['A']).agg({'B':'sum','C':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Problem is not with `NaN`, `NaN` are handled by pandas itself.

Comment: I made a PR regarding this [`GH #35042`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35042) long back how `agg` handles `NaN` but this change will be out in V1.2 docs unfortunately